# how to compare 2 string values for ng-hide

Tags: angularjs, ng-hide

I'm trying to compare a value of an object file.name to see if it matches 2 strings but it doesnt seem to be working right. Not exactly sure what i'm doing wrong...is it because i can't compare more than 2 strings in a or comparator like this?

HTML:

```
<a ng-hide="file.name !== 'application' || 'history application'">
    <span>Hello</span>
</a>
```

i want to hide if my file names do not equal application or history

any ideas?

Comment: Classic mistake. It should be: `ng-hide="file.name !== 'application' || file.name !== 'history application'"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Wasif Khan's answer is correct, it is best practice not to use double negatives where they can be avoided.

```
<a ng-show="file.name === 'application' || file.name === 'history application'">
<span>Hello</span>
</a>
```

By using `ng-show` instead of `ng-hide`, the code becomes more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a ng-hide="file.name !== 'application' || file.name !== 'history application'">
    <span>Hello</span>
</a>
```